# Copy new files (or their hard links) to new location with other folder structure and with new name

Tags: rsync, rename, file-copy, synchronization, hard-link

I hope someone can advise me on a very tedious, repeating task. My university uses Moodle as its eLearning and file exchanging platform. So every now and then our tutors upload new files, that I have to download and save on my filesystem.
Because I don't know when new files are uploaded and it's very annoying to get online regularly just to check whether there are new files, I wanted to use a file-syncing-tool for Moodle like [this](https://github.com/Romern/syncMyMoodle) or [this](https://github.com/MoodleSync/sync-app).

The problem is, that these syncing-tools keep the original filenames (often with special characters and blanks) and there is no way to configure them so that files are downloaded and saved in a customized way (other folder-structure and especially other filenames).

Is there a command, script or program, that can do the following:

1. **Check for new files** in a folder
2. **Copy or just hard link** the new files to **another location** and use a **different filename** (pattern file-renaming would be a very cool feature)

Or is there another (Moodle-)Sync-Tool that is capable of also fulfilling these requirements?

Thank you so much for your help!